# Typo on Contact Us page for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, spelling, tour

I believe there's a typo on the "Contact Us" page of stack overflow.

Please **sent** all your questions and general inquiries to team@stackoverflow.com

should be

Please **send** all your questions and general inquiries to team@stackoverflow.com

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact

Comment: Where is this page?  When I click the `Contact Us` link I get an e-mail.  I also don't see this text on the about page.

Comment: Added link in question.

Comment: The only About Page with the Contact Us extension you're referring to is on Stack Overflow, so I've added the tag for it.